# How to display different content based on dropdown menu selection?

Tags: javascript, html

In the snippet below, I'm using a simple dropdown custom dropdown menu (not a select menu) and I'm trying to display dynamic content based on which menu item is chosen. I'm unsure where to turn from this point.

**How do I display different content based on the dropdown selection?**

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-select');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (dropdown.classList.contains('closed')) {
    dropdown.classList.remove('closed');
  } else {
    dropdown.classList.add('closed');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: purple;
}

.dropdown-select {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
}
.dropdown-select__title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
}
.dropdown-select__title h6 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-select__title img {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.dropdown-select ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-select .menu {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.dropdown-select .menu li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #005fec;
}
.dropdown-select__title, .dropdown-select .menu {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
.dropdown-select.closed .menu {
  height: 0;
}
.dropdown-select.closed img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.tabbed-content {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="dropdown-select closed">
    <div class="dropdown-select__title">
      <h6>Other Releases</h6>
      <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/24/25/25243.png" alt="down caret ">
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Fall 2021</li>
      <li>Summer 2021</li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tabbed-content">
    <div id="1">Fall 2021</div>
    <div id="2">Summer 2021</div>    
  </div>  
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to store which content you want to show when the user clicks it.

To do this, add a `click` event listener to each option that will loop through each possible content option and show the one whose `id` matches the  value of the data attribute while hiding all other ones.

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-select');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (dropdown.classList.contains('closed')) {
      dropdown.classList.remove('closed');
    } else {
      dropdown.classList.add('closed');
    }
});

const options = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li')

const results = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbed-content div')
options.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', function(){
  results.forEach(f => f.style.display = f.id == e.dataset.target ? "block" : "none")
}))
```

```css
.active {
  color: purple;
}

.dropdown-select {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
}
.dropdown-select__title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
}
.dropdown-select__title h6 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown-select__title img {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.dropdown-select ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-select .menu {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.dropdown-select .menu li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #005fec;
}
.dropdown-select__title, .dropdown-select .menu {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
.dropdown-select.closed .menu {
  height: 0;
}
.dropdown-select.closed img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.tabbed-content {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.tabbed-content div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="dropdown-select closed">
    <div class="dropdown-select__title">
      <h6>Other Releases</h6>
      <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/24/25/25243.png" alt="down caret ">
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li data-target="1">Fall 2021</li>
      <li data-target="2">Summer 2021</li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tabbed-content">
    <div id="1" style="display:block">Fall 2021</div>
    <div id="2">Summer 2021</div>    
  </div>  
</main>
```

Comment: And if I wanted to show "Fall 2021" by default?

Comment: @Millhorn Updated answer to show "Fall 2021" by default. Just apply `display:block` to that content option.